# CSS onclick active class is not working

Tags: css

http://jusurubak.azurewebsites.net/www/EnrollmentMethod.aspx

I'm trying to have the buttons stay red when selected...they turn red when hovered. I added an active class to the css but it wont stay red when selected. See the CSS below for the buttons:

```
.btn-red-lg {
display: block;
background-color: #666666;
color: white;
padding: 30px 30px;
margin: 20px auto;
border-radius: 12px;
text-align: center;
-o-transition: background-color .5s;
-moz-transition: background-color .5s;
-webkit-transition: background-color .5s;
transition: background-color .5s;
font-size: 14px;
}

.btn-red-lg:hover {
background-color: #cc0033;
}

.btn-red-lg:active {
background-color: #cc0033;
}

.active:active {
color: #cc0033;;
}
.focus:focus {
 color: #cc0033;
}
:target {
 color: #cc0033;
}

.btn-red-lg h3, .btn-red-lg p {
color: white;
line-height: 1.3em;
}

.btn-red-lg h3 {
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 25px;
font-weight: normal;
margin-bottom: 6px;
}
```

Comment: Posting a link to an arbitrary HTML is useless. Please read [ask] and [mcve].  Add the corresponding HTML. What element type is `.btn-red-lg`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JavaScript, for the best and easiest result. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/stzvebcq/4/

html

```
<button class="button">button</button>
<div class="button">div</div>
<a href="#" class="button">link</a>
```

css

```
.clicked{
    background-color:red;
}
```

js

```
$(".button").on("click",function(){
    $(this).addClass("clicked");
});
```

This example uses jQuery library.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a real HTML button you are applying these classes to? The `:active` pseduo-class will only be activated when the user has clicked on the button and hasn't let go of the click. Perhaps `:focus` is what you're looking for, as that will change the background of the button to red even if the user has let go of the mouse, until the user clicks away.

Comment: Ahh thanks focus worked I forgot to add .btn-red-lg:focus {
    background-color: #cc0033;
}

Comment: @TommyJaramillo Also it won't stay red when the user clicks anywhere alse, when the button loses the focus: https://jsfiddle.net/stzvebcq/2/ I would use JS for this.

Comment: Under the second button if a user selects another button  "Yes" to the right it changes back to grey: https://jusuru.com/www/EnrollmentMethod.aspx

Comment: OK, I just want to answer the question you originally asked, and also you should use smaller examples, not a whole/working page.

Comment: @godzsa How would I get the button to stay red if the user selects another button?\

Comment: @TommyJaramillo use JavaScript, shall I write an example for you?

Answer (score 0):

Because you haven't provided a clear and concise question, it's impossible to know what your problem actually is. You should edit your question to provide a simple example.

I suspect you're currently using jQuery or such to modify the class of an element:

```
$(".btn-red-lg").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

So, although you haven't given all the code necessary to know for sure, it looks like you should edit the 'active' style to **not** include a modifier:

```
.active {
color: #cc0033;;
}
```

I suspect, whatever you're doing with the 'focus' class needs modification too:

```
.focus {
 color: #cc0033;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

So to clarify, are you trying to make the buttons stay red after they've been clicked? If so, try adding a "visited" class:

```
.btn-red-lg:visited {
background-color: #cc0033;
}
```

You can find out some more info about link pseudo-classes here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp

Comment: Why was this down voted?

Comment: this is working only with links, not buttons as OP asked: https://jsfiddle.net/stzvebcq/1/